# Node/MySQL: "Field 'field_name' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm doing a CRUD using Node.js and Sequelize. I have three tables: *psicologos* (psychologists), *pacientes* (patients) and *atendimentos* (appointments). I'm trying to PUT an appointment receiving (and sending) psicologos_id through header as a JWT Token (using req.auth.id), and sending the patient ID through body.

My appointment migration looks ok:

```
    psicologos_id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
  references: { model: 'psicologos', key: 'id' },
  onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
},
pacientes_id: {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
  references: { model: 'pacientes', key: 'id' },
  onUpdate: 'CASCADE', 
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
},
```

And also my associations in models:

**Appointments**:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class Atendimentos extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init({
      data_atendimento: DataTypes.DATE,
      observacao: DataTypes.STRING,
    }, {
      sequelize,
      tableName: 'atendimentos',
    })
  }
 static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.Pacientes, { foreignKey: 'pacientes_id', as: 'pacientes' });
    this.belongsTo(models.Psicologos, { foreignKey: 'psicologos_id', as: 'psicologos' });
  }
}

module.exports = Atendimentos;
```

**Psychologists:**

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")

class Psicologos extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init({
      nome: DataTypes.STRING,
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      senha: DataTypes.STRING,
      apresentacao: DataTypes.STRING,
    }, {
      sequelize,
      tableName: 'psicologos'
    })
  }
   static associate(models) {
      this.hasMany(models.Atendimentos, { foreignKey: 'psicologos_id', as: 'psicologos' });
  }
  }


module.exports = Psicologos;
```

**Patients:**

```
    const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class Pacientes extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init({
      nome: DataTypes.STRING,
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      idade: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    }, {
      sequelize
    })
  }
  static associate(models) {
    this.hasMany(models.Atendimentos, { foreignKey: 'pacientes_id', as: 'pacientes' });
}
}

module.exports = Pacientes;
```

The store method in Appointments controller is also ok:

```
  async store(req, res) {
    const token = req.auth.id;
    const { pacientes_id, data_atendimento, observacao} = req.body;

    const criarAtendimento = {
      psicologos_id: token,
      pacientes_id,
      data_atendimento,
      observacao,
    }

    await Atendimentos.create(criarAtendimento);

    return res.status(201).json(criarAtendimento);

  },
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `atendimentos` (`id`,`data_atendimento`,`observacao`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?);
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error
    at Query.run (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:52:25)
    at /Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:311:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async MySQLQueryInterface.insert (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:308:21)
    at async Atendimentos.save (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:2432:35)
    at async Function.create (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1344:12)
    at async store (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/src/controllers/AtendimentosController.js:35:5) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: Error: Field 'psicologos_id' doesn't have a default value
      at Packet.asError (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
      at Execute.execute (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
    code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
    errno: 1364,
    sqlState: 'HY000',
    sqlMessage: "Field 'psicologos_id' doesn't have a default value",
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `atendimentos` (`id`,`data_atendimento`,`observacao`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?);',
    parameters: [
      '2020-01-01 10:10:00',
      'teste',
      '2022-07-26 04:07:30',
      '2022-07-26 04:07:30'
    ]
  },
  original: Error: Field 'psicologos_id' doesn't have a default value
      at Packet.asError (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
      at Execute.execute (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/pedro/Workspace/Gama Academy/lavie/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
    code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
    errno: 1364,
    sqlState: 'HY000',
    sqlMessage: "Field 'psicologos_id' doesn't have a default value",
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `atendimentos` (`id`,`data_atendimento`,`observacao`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?);',
    parameters: [
      '2020-01-01 10:10:00',
      'teste',
      '2022-07-26 04:07:30',
      '2022-07-26 04:07:30'
    ]
  },
  sql: 'INSERT INTO `atendimentos` (`id`,`data_atendimento`,`observacao`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?);',
  parameters: [
    '2020-01-01 10:10:00',
    'teste',
    '2022-07-26 04:07:30',
    '2022-07-26 04:07:30'
  ]
```

I already tried EVERYTHING, but it keeps don't working.

Could someone help?

Comment: From the error message `psicologos_id` doesn't have a default value, its defined as `allowNull: false`, however when you create `atendimentos`, there is no `psicologos_id`  in the storaging of this record/row.

Comment: I'm sending the token through psicologos_id. If I console.log(token), it shows the psicologos_id (2).